# Doesn't exists Java JRE 17?

Tags: java, jdk, jre

I need the java JRE v17 but I cannot find it. Looking into https://www.java.com I can find only Java JRE v8 only.
Looking in https://www.oracle.com/it/java I can find JDK 17 but not its JRE.
What I'm missing? What should I download if I have to run (not to compile!) a Java17 application?

Comment: I found the answer here........ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55868821/when-jre-was-completely-discontinued-as-a-separate-offering

Comment: [What you want doesn’t exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55868821/when-jre-was-completely-discontinued-as-a-separate-offering)

Comment: Agreed- time to move ahead.

Comment: I cannot understand why I have to create a runtime by myself with jlink if I don't need particular settings or why I should distribute a full jdk... but of course I will adapt to it